# Why is $2^{n}-1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Recently I discovered that $2^{n}-1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$. As I don't have a math background, please tell me what this is called and a proof of why this is the case.

Comment: That isn't quite right -- it should be $2^n-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{2^k} = 1+2+4+\cdots+2^{n-1}$.

Comment: It’s a [geometric series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: Is the "-1" true for every number substituting "2"? More generally, $x^{n}-1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$?

Comment: In general $1+m+\cdots+ m^{n-1} = {m^n-1 \over m-1}$. For $m=2$ this denominator is one, hence the formula.

Comment: The left side is even and the right side is odd, so this is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).  One way to prove the formula is [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

First we check the formula (corrected the left side with $-1)$  for $n=1$:  indeed, $2^1-1=2^0.$

Now we assume it's true for $n=m$ (i.e., $2^m-1=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}2^k$),

and we show it's then true for $n=m+1$:

$2^{m+1}-1=2^m+2^m-1=2^m+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}2^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}2^k.$

Therefore, it's true for $n=1, n=1+1=2, n=2+1=3, n=3+1=4, \dots$

Answer (score 1):

It isn't.

$2^n - 1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$ or equivalently $2^n = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$.

The offset of $1$ is important and unavoidable.

As for why, I *STRONGLY* suggest you play around with it on your own until you make up your own "aha" moment that works for you.

Trust me... you *will* have one.

.... but .... this one was mine:

$2^n = 2*2^{n-1} =$

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} = $

$2^{n-1} + 2*2^{n-2} =$

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2} =$

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2*2^{n-3} = $

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3} + 2^{n-3} =$

........

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3} +..... + 8 + 4 + 2 + 2=$

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3} +..... + 8 + 4 + 2 +1+1=$

$(2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-3} +..... + 8 + 4 + 2 +1)+1=$

$(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k) + 1$.

That was my "aha" moment...

Ohter people have this one:

$1 + (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + .........  + 2^{n-1}) = $

$(1 + 1) + (2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ........ + 2^{n-1}) =$

$2 + (2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ....... + 2^{n-1})=$

$(2 + 2) + (4 + 8 + 16 + ....... + 2^{n-1}) =$

$4 + (4 + 8 + 16 + ......  +2^{n-1}) = $

$(4+4) + (8 + 16 + ...... + 2^{n-1}) =$

$8 + (8 + 16 + ..... + 2^{n-1}) = $

$(8+8) + (16 + ...... + 2^{n-1}) =$

$16 + (16 + ... + 2^{n-1})=$

$(16 + 16) + (..... + 2^{n-1}) = $

$32 + (.... + 2^{n-1})=$.

.... now clearly we can do this indefinately as each step is just ....

$2^k + (2^k + 2^{k+1} + .....) = $

$(2^k +2^k) + (2^{k+1} + ..... ) = $

$2*2^k + (2^{k+1} + ....) =$

$2^{k+1} + (2^{k+1} + ...) =$.

and it is "so clear it is obvious to anyone but a complete dope" that we just adding up two copies of a power of two... which is two times the power of two .... which is two the the *next* power of two.... which we then combine with the next....

So we just do that until we get to the end....

$2^{n-3} + (2^{n-3} + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1})=$

$(2^{n-3} + 2^{n-3}) + (2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1})=$

$2*2^{n-3} +  (2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1})=$

$2^{n-2} + (2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1})=$

$(2^{n-2} + 2^{n-2}) + 2^{n-1}=$

$2*2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1} =$

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} =$

$2*2^{n-1} =$

$2^n$.

So ........

$1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^n$.

That's my *aha* way of looking at it.

....

And  there are others.

find yours

.....

A common but subtle idea is $(2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + ...... + 2 + 1)=$

$1 \cdot (2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + ...... + 2 + 1)=$

$(2-1)(2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + ...... + 2 + 1)=$

$(2^n + 2^{n-1} + ..... + 4 + 2) -(2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + ...... + 2 + 1)=$

$2^n + (2^{n-1} + ..... + 4 + 2) - (2^{n-1} + ..... + 4 + 2) - 1=$

$2^n -1$

That works for some...

Comment: Hi, would it be possible if you can help with some graph theory problems? Like in a room chat or something? I just have many problems, and instead of posting for each on stackoverflow, and you answer regardless here, I thought you may help this way, as I checked the users and found you good at discrete mathematics,

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone ever seen this proof anywhere? ( Different to geometric series proof)

in base 2: $$\underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{n\text{}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$$ 
the next number after $\underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{n\text{}} $ is ${1\underbrace{0\cdots 0}_{n\text{}}} = 2^n$

so 
$\underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{n\text{}} +1  = 2^n$

or

$\underbrace{11\cdots 11}_{n\text{}} = 2^n -1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k  = 2^n -1$$

so in base $x$ we get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k  = x^n -1$$

with the additional benefit of having defined the next number in any base (integer, complex, matrix etc. )

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that a proof.  It relies on accepting equivalent statements that just seem more obvious if stated in a different way.  How do you know that the next number after $111.......11$ is $1000..... 00$?  How do you know base number systems work and make sense?  ... But this is a good argument.  That is circular.

Answer (score 0):

As Hayden has pointed out, the correct expression is $2^n-1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k.$

So to see this, let’s first name the sum $S:=1+2^1+\dots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}.$

The ‘trick’ is to multiply the sum by $1$ in a clever way such that we can cancel some terms. Since $2=2-1$, we can say this:

$$
S=1+2^1+\dots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\\
\implies\\
1\times S = \left(2-1\right)\times \left(1+2^1+\dots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\right)\\
S=2\times\left(1+2^1+\dots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\right)\\
-1\times\left(1+2^1+\dots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\right)\\
= \left(2^1+2^2+\dots+2^{n-1}+2^{n}\right)\\
-\left(1+2^1+\dots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}\right)\\
= 2^n-1.
$$

Hope this helps!
Stay safe

Answer (score 0):

For all *positive integer* $n$ :$$\begin{align}2^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k&&=(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1}+2^n)-(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1})\\[1ex]&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k&&=1+(2+\cdots+2^{n-1}+2^n)-(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1})\\[1ex]&=1+2\sum_{k=1}^n2^{k-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k&&=1+2(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1})-(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1})\\[1ex]&=1+2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k\\[1ex]&=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k&&=1+(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1})\\[3ex]\therefore\quad\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k&=2^n-1\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an observation I made myself as a kid and I proved a version of the formula. It's quite easy to do. This is called a geometric series. You start with a first term, then the rule is that the next term is obtained by multiplying the previous term by a fixed constant. The individual terms are called a geometric "sequence", but the sum of all the terms from first to last (in a finite list of terms) is called a geometric series.

The formula is easy to prove. The usual notation for the constant number you multiply each term by is $r$, denoting the "common ratio".

Let's say we have the series: $S(n) = 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + ...+ r^{n-2} + r^{n-1}$. (series 1)

Note that the argument on the left is $n$ because you're summing $n$ terms on the right.

Now, let's multiply every individual term in the series by $r$. Note that this has the effect of multiplying the entire series by $r$.

$rS(n) = r + r^2 + r^3 + ... r^{n-1} + r^{n}$. (series $2$)

What happens if you take the old series and subtract it from the new one (series $2$ - series $1$)? Note that only the first term in the series $1$ and the last term in series $2$ are "unmatched" and will therefore "survive". All the middle terms vanish.

So you're left with: $rS(n) - S(n)= r^n - 1$

Rearrange that to: $S(n) = \frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$, and you've got your geometric series sum formula. If you put $r = 2$ into that formula, you will reproduce your original observation (with the small correction that others have mentioned), but of course, this is applicable to all $r$.

Note that in the usual statement of the formula, they assume the first term to be $a$ rather than $1$ as I stipulated above. This simply has the effect of mutiplying the entire series by $a$, so the formula is most often stated in texts as $S(n) = \frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$. Not that relevant to your specific question here, but I thought you should know, in order to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed derivation. If I'm not wrong, it should be $S(n) = a \left(\frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}\right)$. Do you mind briefly telling me why there is a need for $a$?

Comment: @AlvinYang It's equivalent. Try multiplying your expression by $-1$ top and bottom. :) But your form is quite important in the case of a convergent infinite series where $|r|<1$, from which the infinite sum formula $S = \frac a{1-r}$ immediately follows by taking the limit. For the finite series case, both forms are equivalent as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a simple proof using telescopic sums :

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, we have the following : $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{2^{k}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{2^{k}\left(2-1\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(2^{k+1}-2^{k}\right)}=2^{n}-1 $$